# Gatling: Enable runMultipleSimulations

Tags: scala, maven, gatling, scala-gatling

I have 30 simulations, and I don't want to crumble all of them into a single simulation file. So I created two files, **Simulation1**.scala and **Simulation2**.
The problem is when I try to run the command `mvn gatling:test` I receive the following error : **"[ERROR] More than 1 simulation to run, need to specify one, or enable runMultipleSimulations"**

My question is, How can I enable this feature?

This is my pom.xml file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>gtg</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <gatling.version>3.6.1</gatling.version>
    <gatling-maven-plugin.version>3.1.2</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
      <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>${gatling.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable it in the configuration (pom.xml) or via command line.

**Configuration**:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <runMultipleSimulations>true</runMultipleSimulations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

**Command line**:

```
mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.runMultipleSimulations=true
```

Comment: @Hosten you're welcome! I forgot to share a link with another configuration keys (it might be helpful for you) - https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/3.4/extensions/maven_plugin/#configuration